# Array of attachment type - how to get a filename for highlighted fragment?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, attachment, highlight, highlighting

I use ElasticSearch to index resources. I create document for each indexed resource. Each resource can contain meta-data and an array of binary files. I decided to handle these binary files with [attachment](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/attachment-type/) type. Meta-data is mapped to simple fields of string type. Binary files are mapped to array field of [attachment](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/attachment-type/) type (field named `attachments`). Everything works fine - I can find my resources based on contents of binary files.

Another ElasticSearch's feature I use is highlighting. I managed to successfully configure highlighting for both meta-data and binary files, but...

When I ask for highlighted fragments of my `attachments` field I only get fragments of these files without any information about source of the fragment (there are many files in attachment array field). I need mapping between highlighted fragment and element of attachment array - for instance the name of the file or at least the index in array.

What I get:

`"attachments" => ["Fragment <em>number</em> one", "Fragment <em>number</em> two"]`

What I need:

`"attachments" => [("file_one.pdf", "Fragment <em>number</em> one"), ("file_two.pdf", "Fragment <em>number</em> two")]`

Without such mapping, the user of application knows that particular resource contains files with keyword but has no indication about the name of the file.

Is it possible to achieve what I need using ElasticSearch? How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want here is to store the filename.
Did you send the filename in your json document? Something like:

```
{
    "my_attachment" : {
        "_content_type" : "application/pdf",
        "_name" : "resource/name/of/my.pdf",
        "content" : "... base64 encoded attachment ..."
    }
}
```

If so, you can probably ask for field `my_attachment._name`.

If it's not the right answer, can you refine a little your question and give a JSON sample document (without the base64 content) and your mapping if any?

UPDATE:

When it come from an array of attachments you can't get from each file it comes because everything is flatten behind the scene. If you really need that, you may want to have a look at nested fields instead.

Comment: I store file name, but I need to associate each highlighting fragment with that file name. My highlighted field contains many files. ElasticSearch API doesn't give me mapping from highlighted fragment to single attachment (one of many elements of array). Take a look at HighlightField class.

Comment: How can I use Text class to get information about file that is highlighted? Highlighted field can be an array (many files).